# Issue with RSpec Loading File

Tags: rspec

I received this error when attempting to start the RSpec tests for my Ruby-on-Rails file. I entered rspec spec/features/creating_article_spec.rb into the terminal,and then this error message came up:rspec/core/configuration.rb:1361:in `load': cannot load such file -- /Users/vbaker/rails_proj/blog_app3/spec/spec/features/creating_article_spec.rb (LoadError)
    from /Users/vbaker/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1361:in`block in load_spec_files'
    from /Users/vbaker/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1359:in `each'
    from /Users/vbaker/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1359:in`load_spec_files'
    from /Users/vbaker/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:102:in `setup'
    from /Users/vbaker/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:88:in`run'
    from /Users/vbaker/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:73:in `run'
    from /Users/vbaker/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:41:in`invoke'
    from /Users/vbaker/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.0/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/vbaker/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/bin/rspec:23:in`load'
    from /Users/vbaker/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/bin/rspec:23:in `'

How do I troubleshoot this issue? What is this indicative of?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably running rspec from the spec/ directory, which is why you see *spec/spec/* in the file path it can't find.  Try changing to the rails root directory (`/Users/vbaker/rails_proj/blog_app3`) and running the same command again.